# Formula in xlR1C1 format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a unique set of values located on sheet3, column A1. I would like to use the countif function to see how many times the value located on sheet3 column1 cell(a(i)) is located on a named range (which is A2 to the bottom of the column) is located on sheet4.  The formula will reside on “sheet3” column 5, for each row of column 5.

```
Set rngOfFindings = Sheets("Sheet4").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))


Count of findings                                        sheet 4 column 1                  value in formula relative to A(i)
Cells(5,i)             =                          countif(rgnOfFindings,                       C[1],RC[-5])
```

Any explanations to the solution will be greatly appreciated (R1C! references as well).

The macro recorder has not been helpful. Trying the formula in EXCEL 2010 has not been illuminating in the least

Comment: The expression `Sheets("Sheet4").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))` is equivalent to `Sheets("Sheet4").Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))` so if the active sheet isn't "Sheet4" then you'll get an error. You might want to use a [With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264723(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you are trying to set the *rngOfFindings* to a group of cells starting at `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2")` and ending at `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").End(xlDown)` on `Sheets("Sheet4")` which is an impossibility.

According to your narrative (*"The formula will reside on “sheet3” column 5, for each row of column 5."*), the `Cells(5, i)` appear to have the row and column parameters switched. The syntax is `Cells(<row number>, <column letter or number>)`.

It isn't completely clear on whether you want to evaluate the `Countif` in VBA and supply the result or put the formula into the cell. I'll try to provide both situations. If you want VBA to evaluate the formula, you need to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(...)` or more simply `Application.Countif(...)`.

The `C[1],RC[-5]` should be `RC[-4]`. If you move 5 columns to the left of column E you go off the worksheet.

Here are some suggestions for modification(s).

```
    Dim i As Long, lr As Long, rngOfFindings As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet4")
        'note the prefixing periods that make each of the three .Range's below to Sheet4
        Set rngOfFindings = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    'set values by evaluating the CountIf here
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            .Cells(i, 5) = Application.CountIf(rngOfFindings, .Cells(i, 1).Value)
        Next i
    End With

    'set formulas on the worksheet
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'formula as A1 cell reference style
        '.Range("E2:E" & lr).Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & rngOfFindings.Address(1, 1, xlA1, True) & ", A2)"
        'formula as A1 cell reference style
        .Range("E2:E" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(" & rngOfFindings.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1, True) & ", RC[-4])"
    End With
    Set rngOfFindings = Nothing
```

Comment: Both of the with statements. The first with has the calculated value in the cell, the second has the formula in the cell that calculates to the same result. not quite sure how the second  one works "=COUNTIF(" & rngOfFindings.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1, True) & ", RC[-4])"; literally put this text in a cell and the value is calculated. How is the "External" evaluated --- the relative to clause of -4 must be column one of  "sheet3" correct? Property Address([RowAbsolute], [ColumnAbsolute], [ReferenceStyle As XlReferenceStyle = xlA1], [External], [RelativeTo]) As String
**thanks for the lesson

Comment: @user249611 - Not sure what to make of all of that but the *external* puts the worksheet name in the address. This is needed to reference cells on Sheet4 within a formula on Sheet3.